# cl.h not found - how to link in makefile

Tags: makefile, opencl

I have a project which requires opencl. I have installed CUDA and openCL on my machine but when I 'make' my project the following error occurs:

```
CL/cl.h: No such file or directory
```

I know that the i can create a hard link (in my unix (ubuntu) system) to fix the problem:

```
ln -s /usr/include/nvidia-current/CL
```

But i consider this a quick fix and not the correct solution. I would like to handle this in my makefile (i guess) so that a simple "make" command would compile. How could I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass an appropriate -I option to the compiler (by setting CPPFLAGS or CFLAGS, for example). `-I/usr/include/nvidia-current` sounds like it'd work.

Comment: I ended up adding it to a separate file handling INCLUDEPATHS for that specific module. But verified that your option does work as well and is indeed the thing I originally asked for. Therefor accepted your answer as final. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, this just helped me to compile darktable with the new 200 series of the nvidia drivers. (There is no debian package yet which delivers the CL/cl.h header file.)

Answer (score 2):

I saw this thread from [compile opencl program using CL/cl.h file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21301905/compile-opencl-program-using-cl-cl-h-file?answertab=votes#tab-top)

I installed 7.5 and added below link in /usr/include, it works for my opencl program. looks like CUDA forget to implement this link after the installation.

```
ln -s /usr/local/cuda-7.5/include/CL /usr/include
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you using [Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=opencl-headers&searchon=names) or [Debian](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=opencl-headers&searchon=names&suite=stable&section=all) distro? Then now you can use this package:

```
sudo apt-get install opencl-headers
```

Comment: Compilation problems? This is the answer.