# cl.h not found - can't instal PyOpenCL

Tags: python

I'am following this install tutorial for PyOpenCL: http://wiki.tiker.net/PyOpenCL/Installation/Linux/Ubuntu and everithing is fine until the make part where i get the following error:

```
$ make
ctags -R src || true
ctags: skipping src: it is not a regular file.
/usr/bin/python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building '_cl' extension
...
In file included from src/wrapper/wrap_cl.cpp:1:0:
src/wrapper/wrap_cl.hpp:27:19: fatal error: CL/cl.h: No Such File or Directory
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
make: ** [all] Error 1
```

I found someone with a similar problem, [cl.h not found - how to link in makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872143/cl-h-not-found-how-to-link-in-makefile) , but i didn't helped me.

When i look into my usr/src directory i can't even find a /wrapper directory, should i create the directory and download this file or this just means that some of the past steps in the tutorial didn't worked on my pc? Any way i can solve this?

I have a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS OS and an ATI video card.

Comment: So you have installed and tested OpenCL itself before trying to build PyOpenCL? (If you're not sure of that, see the [How to set up OpenCL in Linux](http://wiki.tiker.net/OpenCLHowTo) docs.)

Comment: Also, if you've installed OpenCL via Ubuntu packages, you may need a separate package like [`opencl-headers`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=opencl-headers) or `opencl-dev`.